# Get Image Uri in android

Tags: android, arrays, imageview, uri, drawable

I have set of images in drawable.String array s[] stores the names of the images.I want to load images in the imageview from the images stored in those drawable how do i do it.
I tried using

```
imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + my package name + s[position]));
```

I think I am not setting the path correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+packageName+"/drawable/"+yourDrawableName);
```